# Java sending TCP package broadcast from the server

Tags: java, tcp, client

There's a threaded TCP server which creates a new thread for each client connection. Is it necessary to store all the connections in array in order to send a broadcast to all of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doesn't have to be an array, necessarily (it could be a hash or a tree or a bunch of threads with local variables..), but you do need to store all the connections *somewhere* in order to send to them. Otherwise they'd get GCed and closed.